# send mail in background in iPhone 

Tags: iphone, email

I want to send Email in the background of the application. I dont want to show the MailComposer Dialog box to add all the detail.

So How Can I do so ?
Thanks .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You will need to communicated directly with a specified mail server using a [third-party library](http://code.google.com/p/skpsmtpmessage/). If you wish to send the email using the iPhone users email account details, you will have to use Apple's mail composer dialog.

Comment: Is it compulsory to use the mail composer dialog if i am using iPhone users email account details.

Comment: I believe this to be the case

Answer (score 2):

Here's a third party library that will let you send email without the Composer dialog

http://code.google.com/p/skpsmtpmessage/

-t