# Sending an email containing user-entered data

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, email

I am developing an app for a business.  This app is essentially a product order app that takes the products from a database file.  When the file is selected, it moves to a page with options of quantity, length, color, etc. Then, if the purchase is confirmed, it goes to another page to fill out user information.

Is there a way to print the details the user inputs from both pages to an email and send that email to a specific billing address?  To the user it is just simply hitting the confirm button, but in the background it sends an email with all this info. I have found different forums talking about email from an iPhone app but none seem to work the way I need them to.

Comment: possible duplicate of [send mail in background in iPhone ](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1832156/send-mail-in-background-in-iphone)

Answer (score 1):

You can add any text to mail composer like this:

```
MFMailComposeViewController *mailController = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];
[mailController setMessageBody:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"User %@ ordered %d of %@ at a price of %f",
                                orderCustomer,
                                orderQuantity,
                                orderItem,
                                orderPrice]
                        isHTML:NO];
[self presentModalViewController:mailController animated:YES];
[mailController release];
```

As you can see, you can also insert html into the mail message body if you want your order to be formatted nicely.

Comment: In addition, you can use an email service provider that has a JSON API that you can POST to with the user variables to send out an email.

Comment: That sounds/looks pretty good.  I have not gotten to the email part yet so, i will let you know if this works out. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is.  One simple method for capturing user input is to use a screen shot. Then attaching it to an email.  You can render the screen to pdf or image format.

Something like:

```
//draw main window in image context
UIWindow *window=[[[UIApplication sharedApplication] windows] objectAtIndex:0];
[[window layer] renderInContext:context];
//convert to UIImage
UIImage *image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
//clean up
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
//return
return image;
```

As for sending an email in the background you will need to use a third party library.  MFMailComposeViewController can be used to send an email from iOS but it requires the user to confirm the email dialog.